# dynamic scripts creation oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i have a table t1 with base table names and their column names. i want to generate the script for each table with column header separated by pipe delimiter.

```
create table t1 (table_nm varchar2(10) , col_nm varchar2(20));

  INSERT INTO T1  SELECT 'AAA' , 'FNAME' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                         SELECT 'AAA' , 'LNAME' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                         SELECT 'AAA' , 'PH_NO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                         SELECT 'BBB' , 'LAST_NM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                         SELECT 'BBB' , 'EMAIL' FROM DUAL ;
  COMMIT;
```

the code i am trying.

```
 SELECT * FROM
    (
    WITH ABC AS (SELECT TABLE_NM, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,COL_NM,'|').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY COL_NM).GETCLOBVAL(),'|') AS COL 
    from t1 group by table_nm)
     select
      'set termout off '||chr(10)|| 
      'set timing off '||chr(10)||
      'set echo off '||chr(10)||
      'set feedback off '||chr(10)||
      'set linesize 104 '||chr(10)||
      'set pagesize 0 '||CHR(10)||
      'spool /tmp/'||abc.TABLE_NM||'.csv '||CHR(10)||
      'SELECT '||''''||COL||''''||' FROM DUAL;'||CHR(30)||
      'select '||COL||' from '||abc.table_nm||';'||chr(10)||
      'spool off' EXTRACT
      FROM ABC
      );
```

errors i am getting with actual data.

1) ORA-00996: the concatenate operator is ||, not |

expected files/output

```
 AAA.dat
 FNAME|LNAME|PH_NO
 .... some values with pipe delimiter
 ...

 BBB.dat
 LAST_NM|EMAIL
 some values with pipe delimiter
```

could you please help on this.

i have modified the question and removed the first issue.                                  yes i dont need || at the last..i changed in the query as well. After executing the above code in sql developer i am getting the output like

```
"set termout off 
set timing off 
set echo off 
set feedback off 
set linesize 104 
set pagesize 0 
spool /tmp/AAA.dat
SELECT 'FNAME|LNAME|PH_NO' FROM DUAL;
SELECT  FNAME|LNAME|PH_NO FROM AAA;
spool off"
```

the second select statement is giving the error as  :

```
 SELECT  FNAME|LNAME|PH_NO FROM AAA;
 ORA-00996: the concatenate operator is ||, not |
00996. 00000 -  "the concatenate operator is ||, not |"
```

is there any other approach to handle this?

Comment: This should help with your first error. There're some workarounds posted in the answers there. The second error is less clear, though. When exactly does it occur?

Comment: how to build the query like  select FNAME||'|'||LNAME||'|'||PH_NO FROM  T1 as stated above.

Comment: concatenation operator is `||` so if you need to create a literal varchar you can use something like this: `SELECT 'FNAME'||'|'||'LNAME'||'|'||'PH_NO' FROM DUAL;`. You'll need to replace literal values with corresponding columns if you need to select them from your table.

Comment: actually  first statement gives the header column and second should give actual values of those columns, the problem is with second query for which i am not able  to generate the string dynamically.                                                                                  
 SELECT 'FNAME|LNAME|PH_NO' FROM DUAL;
select FNAME||'|'||LNAME||'|'||PH_NO||'|'|| from AAA;

FNAME|LNAME|PH_NO
ROBIN|MEI|902837

Comment: Please, clean up your question. Your first issue takes a lot of space and it was already resolved elsewhere. Concentrate on the actual query, add the definition for `AAA` and post an actual error message. Also, you don't need this last `||` there, as far as I understand.

Comment: i have modified the question and posted the second issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second generated query is using the wrong concatenation operator (`|` instead of `||`):

```
SELECT  FNAME|LNAME|PH_NO FROM AAA;
```

As you need to include the separator itself into the output, you'll need to turn into something like:

```
SELECT  FNAME || '|' || LNAME || '|' || PH_NO FROM AAA;
```

To do this you can replace the separator char (`|`) with a concatenation string (`||'|'||`). You'll also need to escape single quotes in the string literal here (`||''|''||`).

You can do it directly in the generation query:

```
...
'select '|| REPLACE(COL, '|', '||''|''||') ||' from '||abc.table_nm||';'||chr(10)||
...
```

The whole query after updates:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
WITH ABC AS (SELECT TABLE_NM, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,COL_NM,'|').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY COL_NM).GETCLOBVAL(),'|') AS COL 
from t1 group by table_nm)
 select
  'set termout off '||chr(10)|| 
  'set timing off '||chr(10)||
  'set echo off '||chr(10)||
  'set feedback off '||chr(10)||
  'set linesize 104 '||chr(10)||
  'set pagesize 0 '||CHR(10)||
  'spool /tmp/'||abc.TABLE_NM||'.csv '||CHR(10)||
  'SELECT '||''''||COL||''''||' FROM DUAL;'||CHR(30)||
  'select '||REPLACE(COL, '|', '||''|''||')||' from '||abc.table_nm||';'||chr(10)||
  'spool off' EXTRACT
  FROM ABC
  );
```